# JavaScript. Не работают регулярные выражения

Tags: javascript, html

Собственно, выводит несоответствие в каждом выражении при правильном вводе (это можно проверить, если вставить по алерту в каждое условие). Первое поле должно быть 495 или 632, втрое поле должно содержать 3 цифры, третье поле должно содержать 4 цифры.

```js
function checkFields(text1, text2, text3) {
 var pattern = "/495|632/";
 var isCorrect = true;
 if (text1.search(pattern) == -1) {
  isCorrect = false;
 }
 pattern = "/\d{3}/"
 if (text2.search(pattern) == -1) {
  isCorrect = false;
 }
 pattern = "/\d{4}/"
 if (text3.search(pattern) == -1) {
  isCorrect = false;
 }
 if (isCorrect) {
  alert("Спасибо за заказ!");
 } else {
  alert("Неправильный ввод!");
 }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
 <p align="center">
  Номер телефона:
  <input type="text" name="text1">
  -
  <input type="text" name="text2">
  -
  <input type="text" name="text3">
 </p>
 <p align="center">
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="checkFields(text1.value, text2.value, text3.value)">
 </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Кавычки не нужны. Это не php

Answer (score 0):

Alexey Ten дело говорит.

```
function checkFields(text1, text2, text3) {
    var pattern = /495|632/;
    var isCorrect = true;
    if (text1.search(pattern) == -1) {
        isCorrect = false;
    }
    pattern = /\d{3}/;
    if (text2.search(pattern) == -1) {
        isCorrect = false;
    }
    pattern = /\d{4}/;
    if (text3.search(pattern) == -1) {
        isCorrect = false;
    }
    if (isCorrect) {
        alert("Спасибо за заказ!");
    } else {
        alert("Неправильный ввод!");
    }
}
```

Можно короче написать

```
    function checkFields(text1,text2,text3){
        return alert(
            (text1.search(/495|632/) != -1 && 
                text2.search(/\d{3}/) != -1 && 
                text3.search(/\d{4}/) != -1)
                    ?"Спасибо за заказ!"
                    :"Неправильный ввод!"
        );
    }
```